# ASP.NET MVC - Forcing custom base class for Razor (cshtml) files

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently using this syntax to specify a custom Razor page base class and model type:

```
@inherits MyWebViewPage<MyModel>
```

Newer builds of Razor support a new directive to simplify this code:

```
@model MyModel
```

I'd like to use this but I can't find a way to make it work with my custom base class.  Is there a way to specify this at a global level for my site?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In views/web.config modify

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

to your class

Answer (score 19):

Tried to specify this in `Views/Web.config`?

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="MyUberCustomBaseClass">
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanks Arnis.  I accepted Lukáš's answer as he answered 30 seconds or so before you, and your answers are otherwise identical :)

Comment: @Drew it's fine. Main thing is that You found a solution.